# Calabash Android - Query url of webview

Tags: android, webview, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I would like query the url of the webview. I'm trying

```
query("android.webkit.WebView marked:'web view'", :getUrl)
```

I am getting an error saying

```
 [0] {
             "error" => nil,
     "receiverClass" => "android.webkit.WebView",
    "receiverString" => "android.webkit.WebView{e0d51d8 VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,147-1080,1731 #7f0f00cd app:id/kb_webview}",
        "methodName" => "Property[getUrl]"
}
```

Can any one shed some light on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have opportunity to test it, but try like this:

```
query ("android.webkit.WebView marked:'web view'"), :getUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `query("android.webkit.WebView marked:'web view' css:'*' {href CONTAINS 'http'}")`